# How to create XPath for the tags not having id or name

Tags: html

[alt text http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/9558/testxb.png](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/9558/testxb.png)

Please look into the tag sequence(click on the link) and want to know xpath for this.
None of the tag having ID's or names.

I need to use xpath in the following command.

selenium.click("XPath goes here");

Regards
Sai

Comment: Just use `.className` instead of `#id`?

Comment: Firefox's Firebug plugin (and the Firefinder plugin to Firebug (woo, plugins for plugins)) have some tools to quickly build XPath statements pointing at arbitrary HTML elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
//button[@class='hdm-button'][2]
```